# MetPy interpolate_to_grid function returning unexpected nan based on data domain

Tags: grid, interpolation, metpy

I have been using the "Gridding METAR Observations" example code from MetPy Mondays #154 for some time without any issues.  Up until recently, I passed the entire data set without restrictions (except to exclude stations near the South Pole, which were blowing up the Lambert Conformal transformation.)

Recently, I tried to restrict the domain of the METAR data I process to North America.  At this point, MetPy's *interpolate_to_grid* function seems to be returning *nan* when it did not previously. Since my region of interest is far removed from the boundaries of the data set, I expected no effect on contours derived from the interpolated data; instead there is a profound effect (please see the example below.)  I tried to interpolate over regions of missing data (*nan*) using SciPy's *interp2d* function, but there are too many *nan* to overcome with that "bandaid step".

**Question**:  Is this expected behavior with *interpolate_to_grid*, or am I using it incorrectly?  I can alway continue to use the entire data set, but that does slow things down a bit.  Thanks for any help understanding this.

In the following example, I am using the 00Z.TXT file from https://*tgftp.nws.noaa.gov*/data/observations/metar/cycles/, but I am seeing this with METAR data from other sources.

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.feature as cfeature
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

from metpy.io import parse_metar_file
from metpy.interpolate import interpolate_to_grid, remove_nan_observations

%matplotlib inline

#  If we are getting data from the filesystem:
month=10
fp = '00Z.TXT'
df0 = parse_metar_file(fp, month=month)

#  To avoid the Lambert Conformal transformation from blowing up
#  at the South Pole if reports from Antarctica are present:
q = df0.loc[df0['latitude'].values>=-30]
df = q

# Set up the map projection
mapcrs = ccrs.LambertConformal(central_longitude=-100, central_latitude=35,standard_parallels=(30,60))
datacrs= ccrs.PlateCarree()

# 1) Remove NaN
df1=df.dropna(subset=['latitude','longitude','air_temperature'])
lon1=df1['longitude'].values
lat1=df1['latitude'].values
xp1 , yp1 , _ = mapcrs.transform_points(datacrs, lon1, lat1).T

#  Interpolate observation data onto grid.
xm1, ym1, tmp = remove_nan_observations(xp1, yp1, df1['air_temperature'].values)
Tgridx, Tgridy, Temp = interpolate_to_grid(xm1, ym1, tmp, hres = 20000, interp_type='cressman')

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=mapcrs)
ax.set_extent([-105, -95, 32, 40],datacrs)
ax.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('50m'))
ax.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'))
c = ax.contour(Tgridx, Tgridy, Temp ,levels=50)
```

The output is what I expect to see:
[image]

When I take the same dataset and restrict its domain, we get discontinuous contours:

```py
#  Limit to ~ North America
q = df0.loc[(df0['latitude'].values>=20) & (df0['latitude'].values<=70) &
(df0['longitude'].values>=-150) & (df0['longitude'].values<=-60)]
df = q

# 1) Remove NaN
df2=df.dropna(subset=['latitude','longitude','air_temperature'])
lon2=df2['longitude'].values
lat2=df2['latitude'].values
xp2 , yp2 , _ = mapcrs.transform_points(datacrs, lon2, lat2).T

#  Interpolate observation data onto grid.
xm2, ym2, tmp2 = remove_nan_observations(xp2, yp2, df2['air_temperature'].values)
Tgridx2, Tgridy2, Temp2 = interpolate_to_grid(xm2, ym2, tmp2, hres = 20000, interp_type='cressman')

fig2 = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
ax2 = fig2.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=mapcrs)
ax2.set_extent([-105, -95, 32, 40],datacrs)
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('50m'))
ax2.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'))
c2 = ax2.contour(Tgridx2, Tgridy2, Temp2 ,levels=50)
```

[image]

I did confirm the station locations are actually in North America (not shown.)  I then checked for the locations of *nan* in the interpolated data and found the contours break at regions filled with *nan*.  As a final figure, I plot the locations of *nan*(blue), station locations (green) as well as the broken contours.

```py
xn , yn = np.where(np.isnan(Temp2))
fig4 = plt.figure(figsize=(20,15))
ax4 = fig4.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=mapcrs)
ax4.set_extent([-105, -95, 32, 40],datacrs)

ax4.add_feature(cfeature.COASTLINE.with_scale('50m'))
ax4.add_feature(cfeature.STATES.with_scale('50m'))

c4 = ax4.contour(Tgridx2, Tgridy2, Temp2 ,levels=50)
plt.scatter(df2['longitude'],df2['latitude'],transform=datacrs,color='lightgreen')
plt.scatter(Tgridx2[xn,yn], Tgridy2[xn,yn])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tricky one to figure out. What's going on is that MetPy's implementation for Cressman (and Barnes) interpolation uses a maximum search radius for points included in the distance-weighted average. If you don't specify this maximum search radius, it uses 5 times the average minimum spacing between stations.

By subsetting your data to approximately North America, you have constructed  subset of the data where the stations are closer together; this results in a smaller search radius (it is decreasing from ~150km to ~66km). This is obviously producing suboptimal results for your dataset, I think in part because there are limited stations. I plotted the station locations on top of the results using a 66km search radius here:

[image: Contour of station data with locations]

You can see the dropouts are where there are sizable gaps between stations. The best solution here is to manually specify the `search_radius` argument to something like 120km, which seems to give reasonable results:

```
 Tgridx, Tgridy, Temp = interpolate_to_grid(xp1, yp1, df1['air_temperature'].values,
                                            hres=20000, interp_type='cressman',
                                            search_radius=120000)
```

[image: Station contours and locations]

Though really the appropriate value for `search_radius` will depend on what features you're trying to analyze and how far you're willing to spread values away from the observation point. I'll note you can also adjust some of this with other parameters for Cressman in `interpolate_to_grid`.

Comment: Very nice.  Thank you very much!  This makes a lot of sense to me now and I have a strategy for  dealing with it.  I confess I would not have tried varying the search radius as you suggest.  Very much appreciated!